# Time reset when refresh the page in jQuery Classy Countdown

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

I want to set the countdown timer to January 1 2017. But when refresh the page the countdown reset and started counting again as 24 days 23 hours 50 minutes ..
[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waRMb.jpg)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#countdown4').ClassyCountdown({
            end: $.now() + 2160000,
            labels: true,
            style: {
                element: "",
                textResponsive: .5,
                days: {
                    gauge: {
                        thickness: .03,
                        bgColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
                        fgColor: "#1abc9c"
                    },
                    textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#fff;'
                },
                hours: {
                    gauge: {
                        thickness: .03,
                        bgColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
                        fgColor: "#2980b9"
                    },
                    textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#fff;'
                },
                minutes: {
                    gauge: {
                        thickness: .03,
                        bgColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
                        fgColor: "#8e44ad"
                    },
                    textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#fff;'
                },
                seconds: {
                    gauge: {
                        thickness: .03,
                        bgColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
                        fgColor: "#f39c12"
                    },
                    textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#fff;'
                }

            },
            onEndCallback: function() {
                console.log("Time out!");
            }
        });

    });
```

check the code i use

Comment: Can you share what you try?

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Why do you want to countdown to Jan, 1st 2016 - which is in the past. And your end is always 25 days from now: end: $.now() + 2160000 - Please tell us, what exactly you want.

Comment: sorry the coutdown date is Jan 1st 2017

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript method `SetInterval()` for create count down. It count time down every second (1000 milliseconds).

This sample show how count time to end of year

```
    $(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
        date_future = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() +1, 0, 1);
        date_now = new Date();

        seconds = Math.floor((date_future - (date_now))/1000);
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
        days = Math.floor(hours/24);

        hours = hours-(days*24);
        minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
        seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);

        $("#timeDay").text(days);
        $("#timeHours").text(hours);
        $("#timeMinutes").text(minutes);
        $("#timeSeconds").text(seconds);
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Helped a lot for me